# XPages: Using a View with FTSearch applied as a source to dynamicViewPanel

Tags: xpages

I would like to take a dominoView, apply a FTSearch in beforePageLoad, and then use that view as the value in a dynamicViewPanel to show the search results.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, it seems like the dynamicViewPanel is showing the full view, as if the search wasn't performed.  The FTSearch is being done in beforePageLoad as expected, though.  Should this work?  (If not, for some reason, then it seems like a workaround would be to store the search results in beforePageLoad into a javascript array and use that as the value of a repeat instead of using a dynamicViewPanel.)

TIA!
- Reid

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the Search property of the view data source? This does a FT search. You can bind that property to a viewScope variable that holds your FT search query and if you don't want to filter the view then just set the viewScope variable to "".

Comment: Thanks, Howard.  I was aware of that approach, though the design had evolved away from that for some reason.  (I'm working with some old code.)  Still, I'd like to know the answer to my question in case the Search property approach can't be used.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing in the beforePageLoad, maybe post your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post my code.  I am building a query string and calling view1.FTSearch() with it, though.  I'm also iterating through the view in that function (using getFirstEntry/getNextEntry), building up some arrays for other purposes, and that seems to work okay.

Comment: I don't think that will work... Your filtering has to be done through the search property from what I have tried before...

Comment: That seems to verify that what I'm seeing is correct then... wish I knew why!

Comment: `view1` is not the Notes View but a wrapper around the View, so I don't think it has an `FTSearch()` method. Because ViewEntries can't be stored between requests, it will be performing the search itself against the View, then caching either IDs or column values and using that collection of Java objects. I don't know if it's storing all results or searching again as you page, possibly the former. It may be caching and checking to see if the search criteria have changed, in which case searching again and going back to page 1. So you need to code (or set in beforePageLoad) the search property.

Comment: Hm....  If I print the typeof view1 in beforePageLoad, it says lotus.domino.local.View.  It certainly seems to have a valid FTsearch method, so I'm not sure what you mean, Paul.  In any case, it's interesting to think about what actually occurs behind the scenes to support this functionality.